# Stop execute stuff with pressing a button

Tags: batch-file

Seriously I couldn't find a better title for this, I want that if I press a button in a batch file that nothing happens. Currently it executes every time I press a button the code below again...

Tried different things like sleep instead of timeout or tried without echo, nothing helped, I think I need to include something in there to stop it.

```
@echo off
:loop
start OpenServer.bat
timeout 21600
Taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - OpenServer.bat"
goto loop
```

I expect that nothing happens when I press any button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output of `timeout /?`:

> This utility accepts a timeout parameter to wait for the specified
>   time period (in seconds) **or until any key is pressed**. It also
>   accepts a parameter to ignore the key press.

To get the timeout to ignore keypresses, use `timeout 21600 /nobreak` instead.